# Combining android and gwt?

Tags: java, android, cordova, gwt

I'd like to develop a hybrid app using mgwt-phonegap.

I found this [link](http://www.e-nature.ch/tech/wrapping-mgwt-webapp-with-phonegap-into-a-native-android-app/) :

What I don't get is: Why is he putting the gwt-code into the android project's folder? Isn't it unecessary to use Android at all when you use mgwt and phonegap? I thought, that was the whole idea behind it?

What do you get from creating an android project and then putting your gwt code inside it?

Can you use gwt to convert a standard android app into a hybrid app for different platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not read the tutorial you mention, but with phonegap you can create a native shell, which is basically a WebView with some hooks to call native stuff, In this shell you place your HTML/Javascript which in your case is the compiled code of a mgwt project. The android project you create it with phonegap, their site has a tutorial, I think you should read more about phonegap.

Comment: aah okay... I think the tutorial shows it like this because they didnt use phonegap build. which takes care of this for you. Otherwise, you'd have to create separate projects for Android, iOs and so on.